# Take picture in UWP with Plugin.Media

Tags: image, uwp

In a xaml xamarin project pcl (UWP) I can take a photo, however when the screen is opened to accept the image, it appears weakly in the background and the crop grid is summarized in the upper right corner.
All was well until one of the last updates.
Below I send the images of what happens.
My Windows version is 1703 OS Build 15063.540
My Windows Camera Version is 1017.727.20.0
How I solve this.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It will be easier for you to get help if you post actual code

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the issue with the following code. However, I could not reproduce. And The `Gridlines` that you mentioned is `scale` that to crop the photo. If you have set the selection, and the content out of selection will be weakly. It is by design.

```
takePhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
 {

     if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
     {
         await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
         return;
     }

     var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
     {
         PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Full,
         Directory = "Sample",
         Name = "test.jpg"
     });

     if (file == null)
         return;

     await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

     image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
     {
         var stream = file.GetStream();
         file.Dispose();
         return stream;
     });
 };
```

[image]

If the issue is not caused by the inappropriate selection that above mentioned, you could check the camera physical device.